# Can I run 2 different apache servers on the same machine on different ports?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, port, local-area-network

Is it possible? If it is the case, how can I do it? I need it since I want to test communication between web servers on a local network and I do not have a local network. I just have one computer. I use apache on Windows 7.

Comment: Have you considered just using something like VirtualBox or Vmware to setup multiple virtual machines?  Virtual machines will give you a more realistic setup, and it will probably be a lot easier to setup.

Comment: @Zoredache, I actually did not considered this possibility since I did not know about it. Thanks for the advice, I will consider this possibility.

Comment: I'm curious about what sort of communication you're trying to test because web sites normally don't talk to each other. Perhaps we can suggest another method.

Comment: @John Gardeniers, web sites talk to each other all the time these days.  It is call *web-services*.

Comment: @Zoredache, that's a pretty small percentage of sites though, so not the norm.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible.

You just have to use two different configuration files which differ (at least) in their [Listen](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) directives. Also read [Setting which addresses and ports Apache uses](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html).